# Capturing error messages when calling Matlab from Linux bash

Tags: bash, matlab, error-handling

I have the following matlab script, called `test.m`:

```
disp('Hello')
error('Oooops')
```

I run it from bash, using:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -r  "try; cd <the appropriate folder>; test ; catch; end; quit"
```

The output is

> Hello

In other words, I do not manage to get the error text from the bash

Answer (score 2):

You are catching the error, without doing anything with the encountered error. Instead, catch the exception and display it. In a script/function this would look like:

```
try
    someNonExistingFunction()
catch ME
    disp(ME)
end
```

Which will display the following:

```
ME = 
  MException with properties:

    identifier: 'MATLAB:UndefinedFunction'
       message: 'Undefined function or variable 'someNonExistingFunction'.'
         cause: {}
         stack: [0×1 struct]
    Correction: []
```

When calling from bash, you could do this:

```
matlab -nodisplay -r "try; someFunction(); catch ME; disp(ME); end; quit"
```

This will make sure that you do see the error message (and the line the error occured if you display `ME.stack`), but allows to execute the last `quit` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MATLAB R2019b, use [the new `-batch` command line option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html#buknt99-1-option1optionN):

```sh
matlab -batch "cd <the appropriate folder>; test"
```

or

```sh
( cd <the appropriate folder> ; matlab -batch test )
```

With this option it is no longer necessary to catch errors and explicitly call `exit`, MATLAB exits after the given statement is finished. It also avoids loading the desktop, always writing output to stdout and stderr.